# How do you solve the error message " 'class_name' object has no attribute 'driver' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, safari, webdriver

I have installed Safari webdriver and Selenium, yet when I execute the following code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

from time import sleep


class class_name:
    def _init_(self, username, pw):
        self.username = username
        self.password = pw
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari()


        sleep(2)

    def login(self):

        self.driver.get("https://google.com")



class_name().login()
```

The following error message pops up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/malachinoel/PycharmProjects/MajorTomtoGroundControl/yes.py", line 22, in <module>
    class_name().login()
  File "/Users/malachinoel/PycharmProjects/MajorTomtoGroundControl/yes.py", line 18, in login
    self.driver.get("https://google.com")
AttributeError: 'class_name' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide the _full_ error message?

Comment: Do show us full code, hard to tell the problem with only an excerpt

Comment: Please provide the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your code appears to be extracted from a class definition, but what you've posted has no `__init__` to set the attribute you're trying to access.  I think perhaps you misspelled it: one underscore, when two are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, a member should def before init if not define as parameter in the **init**:

```
class class_name:
driver = None

def __init__(self, username, pw):
    self.username = username
    self.password = pw
    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a parameter called driver, and use **init** instead of *init*:

```
def __init__(self, username, pw, driver):
    self.username = username
    self.pw = pw
    self.driver = driver
```

Then, you can put `webdriver.Safari()` as the driver paramter when you are using the class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `__init__` is missing an underscore on each side. I also suggest saving your object in a variable or your `class_name().login()` will occasionally get garbage collected and the browser will close as it is no longer in scope. `name = class_name().login()` is an easy fix to this.